# Adding extra files needed for build after using svn.... IntelliJ or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

Ok guys,

I have checked out a project using svn but I can not build because I get a build path error. I need access to a folder called "common" which has the other resources I need to build which is seperate directory on the server which is not part of the project. How can I include that directory so I can build? Sorry I am new to SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In intellij, you can open up your 'Project Structure' and navigate to your module. Go to the 'Sources' tab and you can add your other paths there. This is assuming you can access your 'common' directory from where you want to build.